# batch rename files and keep the last dash

Tags: windows, powershell

I have many many files in one folder, which look like this:

- E123_1_410_4.03_97166_456_2.B.pdf
- E123-1-410-4.03-97166-456_2.B.pdf

I can change all the underscores, but not just 5 of them.

```
 $names = "AD1-D-1234-3456-01","111-D-abcd-3456-01","abc-d-efgi-jklm-no","xxx-xx-xxxx-xxxx-xx"
    
 $names |
     ForEach-Object{
             $new = $_ -replace '(?x)
                                     ^               # beginning of string
                                     (               # begin group 1
                                         [^-]{3}     # a pattern of three non-hyphen characters
                                 )                   # end of group 1
                                 -                   # a hyphen
                                 (                   # begin group 2
                                     [^-]            # a non-hyphen (one character)
                                     -               # a hyphen
                                     [^-]{4}         # a pattern of non-hyphen characters four characters in length
                                     -               # a hyphen
                                     [^-]{4}         # a pattern of non-hyphen characters four characters in length
                                 )                   # end of group 2
                                 -                   # a hyphen
                                 (                   # begin group 3
                                     [^-]{2}         # a pattern of non-hyphen characters two characters in length
                                 )                   # end of group 3
                                 $                   # end of string
                                ', '$1_$2_$3'        # put the groups back in order and insert "_" between the three groups
    
     if ($new -eq $_){                               # check to see if the substitution worked. I.e., was the pattern in $_ correct
             Write-Host "Replacement failed for '$_'"
         }
         else{
             $new
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will rename the files by replacing all underscores in it to dashes, **except** for the last underscore:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\Where\The\Files\Are' -Filter '*_*.*' -File) | Rename-Item -NewName {
    $prefix, $postfix = $_.Name -split '^(.+)(_[^_]+)$' -ne ''
    "{0}$postfix" -f ($prefix -replace '_', '-')
} -WhatIf
```

- I have put the `Get-ChildItem` inside brackets to let it finish gathering the files first. If you leave that out, there is the possibility it might pick up files that were already renamed which is a waste of time.
- The added switch `_WhatIf` is a safety device. This lets you see in the console window what the code *would* rename. If you are satisfied this is correct, remove the `-WhatIf` switch and run the code again so the files actually are renamed.

Examples:

```
X:\Where\The\Files\Are\111_D_abcd_3456_01_qqq_7C.pdf     --> X:\Where\The\Files\Are\111-D-abcd-3456-01-qqq_7C.pdf
X:\Where\The\Files\Are\AD1_D-1234_3456-01_xyz_3.A.pdf    --> X:\Where\The\Files\Are\AD1-D-1234-3456-01-xyz_3.A.pdf
X:\Where\The\Files\Are\E123_1_410_4.03_97166_456_2.B.pdf --> X:\Where\The\Files\Are\E123-1-410-4.03-97166-456_2.B.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the last underscore when renaming your file, use **split** to deconstruct part of the word, and reconstruct the name by using a loop. At last add the dash a the end. In this way whatever the number of underscores, you can replace all of them.

**Working code:**

```
    $names = "E123_1_410_4.03_97166_456-test-test_2.pdf", "E123_1_410_4.03_97166_456_2.B.pdf"
   
 $names |
     ForEach-Object{
             $new = [string]::empty;
             #split 
             $tab = $_.split("_");
             
             #do nothing if there is only one or no dash
             if($tab.count -gt 2){
                
             
             
             #reconstruct by using keep a dash at the end 
             $new = $tab[0];
             for($i = 1; $i -lt $tab.count - 1; $i++){
                $txt = $tab[$i];
                $new += "-" + $txt ;
             }
             
             #add last dash 
             $txt = $tab[$tab.count - 1];
             $new += "_" + $txt;
             
             
             
    
     if ($new -eq $_){                               # check to see if the substitution worked. I.e., was the pattern in $_ correct
             Write-Host "Replacement failed for '$_'"
         }
         else{
            write-Host $new;
         }
             }
     }
```